# NGINX proxy_pass to another port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, proxy, auth-request

I am trying to do an auth_request in nginx by proxy pass but I keep getting:

```
1 auth request unexpected status: 301
```

here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen      8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /my_location/ {
        auth_request /access/auth;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location /access/auth/{
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:5029/server_alias/web_service_name;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

The request should be sent to the apache server which is listening on port 5029.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I guess, you should learn how `proxy_pass` and `auth_request` work.

Comment: Based on the answer of the problem, I guess you should learn some reading. @AlexeyTen

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer for anyone facing the same problem Only a backslash was missing in auth_request path.

```
location /my_location/ {
    auth_request /access/auth/;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem too. Thank you!

Comment: If no backslash as suffix, nginx would always sent a response with status 301 to client.